# Which addressing mode permits relocation without any change whatsoever in the code?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

The options are :

1. Indexed addressing
2. Base register addressing
3. PC relative addressing

Indexed and Base register addressing both work by adding the content of their respective register (Index / Base register) to the address mentioned in the address code.
[Though the subtle difference is Index register has its content as "index" of the array while the Base register has its content as "base" address of the array]

To make the code relocatable, only the content of the Base / Index register needs to be changed, but that too can only be accomplished by executing some additional code.

PC relative mode just references the other instructions relative to the current PC contents.

So, is option 3 the best answer ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple parts: 
- Data: this is about loading values that are in a binary
- Code: this is about jumps and calls

Data doesn't matter much. Code is more interesting. 
In the absolute case you call . You write the code so  is right most of the time. If it is not, the loader patches it right there in the code.

In the relative case, you have to call  which then calls  So one extra hop.

In the end 3 is more flexible but might have a small runtime overhead.
Another reason why PC relative all the time can have extra costs is that the PC distance might not be the whole address space.

Absolute addressing can be a small optimization. But also costs more to start when things go wrong.